# sqoop import create hive table, the table not found in the specified database

Tags: import, sqoop

I write the following **sqoop** command :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/export --username root --password cloudera --table cust --create-hive-table --fields-terminated-by ' '  --hive-table default.cust -m 1
```

Then, I could not found the table in default database but the file appeared in **/user/cloudera/cust**

Comment: Try using hive-import and hive-overwrite in your sqoop command and mention the —target-dir —hive-table in sqoop command.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. It is true, I have to put hive-import.

Comment: Glad to hear, I just added the answer it will help other people who face the same issue. Can you please tick my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `—hive-import` and `-hive-overwrite` if it is a overwrite table. You can also mention the `—target-dir`